# How to solve TypeError: cannot serialize float Python Elementtree

Tags: python, serialization, pandas, elementtree, marytts

I got a debugging question.

Since I am quite new here, please forgive possible janky walls-of-text.

After many hours I finally got `elementtree` to do what I want, but I cannot output my results, because

```
tree.write("output3.xml")
```

as well as

```
print(ET.tostring(root))
```

gives me

> TypeError: cannot serialize 0.029999999999999999 (type float64)

I don't know what you guys need to help me out here, all the source code is sorta lengthy. So is the error message. But that's a little easier, so I post it here...

notes in advance:

- As far as I can see and Ctrl+F I don't have that 0.029999999... in my data
- All numerics are rounded to 2 decimals in my data
- does rounding change anything at all btw? Or is it just for display?
- I am really very confused by this, especially because there seem to be no googleable similar cases, just almost-but-not-entirely-enough ones.

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 tree.write("output3.xml")
>
> C:\Anaconda\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.pyc in write(self,
>   file_or_filename, encoding, xml_declaration, default_namespace,
>   method)
>       818                 )
>       819             serialize = _serialize[method]
>   --> 820             serialize(write, self._root, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
>       821         if file_or_filename is not file:
>       822             file.close()
>
> C:\Anaconda\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.pyc in _serialize_xml(write,
>   elem, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
>       937                     write(_escape_cdata(text, encoding))
>       938                 for e in elem:
>   --> 939                     _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
>       940                 write("")
>       941             else:
>
> C:\Anaconda\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.pyc in _serialize_xml(write,
>   elem, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
>       937                     write(_escape_cdata(text, encoding))
>       938                 for e in elem:
>   --> 939                     _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
>       940                 write("")
>       941             else:
>
> C:\Anaconda\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.pyc in _serialize_xml(write,
>   elem, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
>       937                     write(_escape_cdata(text, encoding))
>       938                 for e in elem:
>   --> 939                     _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
>       940                 write("")
>       941             else:
>
> C:\Anaconda\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.pyc in _serialize_xml(write,
>   elem, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
>       937                     write(_escape_cdata(text, encoding))
>       938                 for e in elem:
>   --> 939                     _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
>       940                 write("")
>       941             else:
>
> C:\Anaconda\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.pyc in _serialize_xml(write,
>   elem, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
>       937                     write(_escape_cdata(text, encoding))
>       938                 for e in elem:
>   --> 939                     _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
>       940                 write("")
>       941             else:
>
> C:\Anaconda\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.pyc in _serialize_xml(write,
>   elem, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
>       930                         v = qnames[v.text]
>       931                     else:
>   --> 932                         v = _escape_attrib(v, encoding)
>       933                     write(" %s=\"%s\"" % (qnames[k], v))
>       934             if text or len(elem):
>
> C:\Anaconda\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.pyc in _escape_attrib(text,
>   encoding)    1090         return text.encode(encoding,
>   "xmlcharrefreplace")    1091     except (TypeError, AttributeError):
>   -> 1092         _raise_serialization_error(text)    1093     1094 def _escape_attrib_html(text, encoding):
>
> C:\Anaconda\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.pyc in
>   _raise_serialization_error(text)    1050 def _raise_serialization_error(text):    1051     raise TypeError(
>   -> 1052         "cannot serialize %r (type %s)" % (text, type(text).**name**)    1053         )    1054
>
> TypeError: cannot serialize 0.029999999999999999 (type float64)

**Okay, first edits first.** I will paste screenshots of the essences I am trying to achieve.

The task at hand is using python with pandas and `elementtree` to update an xml file.

The file is outputted by the Text-To-Speech system MARY and contains information how to synthesize a given utterance.

That file has the following structure (simplified)

```
<phrase>
<word>
<syllable = "t e s t">
<phone = "t" duration = "30" end = "230">
<phone = "e" duration = "90" end = "320" f0 = "(25,144)(50,145)(75,150)(100,149)">
...and so on...see screenshot for details...
```

this means that for any given phone/sound in the word "test" the XML contains acoustic information, in this order: Type of sound, length, endpoint in time, pitch (f0) curve.
The f0 curve consists of tuples (timepoint @ percentage of time elapsed, Pitch (in Hertz) @ timepoint)

From another program, PRAAT, I obtained updated timing and pitch information, stored in a dataframe, see other screenshot.

My Python parses the xml and overwrites the acoustic info for each sound. But then fails to output.

The float-for-beginners link in the answer made things a little clearer. Apparently rounding does not help at all.

I could possibly live without floats and use strings, but curiously the things in my Dataframe appear to BE strings, since when I try to apply the round() function on any value extracted from there, it will protest that the input is not a float...

screenys:

ya. great. need more reputation for images. rats. so just links.

http://puu.sh/bzQQr/6fed162db8.png

http://puu.sh/bzQNq/23490bfb63.png

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**You should boil your problem down to a [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).** This may help you solve the problem on your own, but more importantly, anyone who reads it now basically has to guess at your intentions since you haven't showed examples of your code, the input, or the intended output.

Likely the problem is that you are setting the value of an `ElementTree` attribute or `text` to a [Numpy `float64` object](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html). The ElementTree library doesn't know about the `float64` type and won't try to silently convert it to a string.

For example, you may have something like this in your code (I have no idea exactly how your code works since you haven't shown it):

```
# the value 0.3 cannot be exactly represented in floating points
# read this for starters: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html
et.find(".//element").text = float64(0.3)
```

You should replace it with this:

```
et.find(".//element").text = str(float64(0.3))
```

Python itself, and most of its standard libraries, are strict about type-checking and will not automatically convert from numeric types to strings.

Comment: OK, I will try to figure out how to conveniently provide code snippets. Like I said before, the code is quite lentghy and I have no clue which part is the problem. So I will try to tree.write a simple example using less but comparable data and see what happens. I will edit helpful information as soon as I have it...

Comment: Thanks, Dan, your answer guided me in the correct direction. After all, I succeeded by applying the str() method to all data after they were completely calculated.

Comment: Your update helps, but what you really need to figure out is exactly where in your code you're trying to use a non-string value in your XML code. So you should try to isolate the problematic section of code and share that if you still need help with it. Applying `str()` to everything may work in your case but may inadvertently mangle some data structures if you're not careful too. (BTW, I used to use Praat back in undergrad linguistics and TTS software job... really cool software.)

Answer (score 1):

(as suggested above) Simply convert the floats that you are adding to your ElementTree into strings.

```
str(floatValue)
```

Comment: This just worked for me

Answer (score -1):

For most people this will be resolved if you cross check and make sure all values assigned to attributes, tags are cast to string format

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).