# TypeError: cannot serialize x.x (type float) (Elementtree)

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree

I'm trying to print an `ElementTree` using python 3.6.  Here is a reproducible example of my code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
root = ET.Element('gpx')
el = ET.SubElement(root, 'test')
el.text = 0.3
print(ET.dump(root))
```

Error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1177, in dump
    elem.write(sys.stdout, encoding="unicode")
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 776, in write
    short_empty_elements=short_empty_elements)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 941, in _serialize_xml
    short_empty_elements=short_empty_elements)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 938, in _serialize_xml
    write(_escape_cdata(text))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1074, in _escape_cdata
    _raise_serialization_error(text)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1057, in _raise_serialization_error
    "cannot serialize %r (type %s)" % (text, type(text).__name__)
TypeError: cannot serialize 0.3 (type float)
```

Serializing a float type must be something very commonly done, buut I can't find a satisfactory answer on how to do this- what is the standard method?

Research:

I can find [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839855/how-to-solve-typeerror-cannot-serialize-float-python-elementtree) on stack overflow about this, but it suggests cooecing the float to a string,I need the output to be numeric.

There's an [old discussion](https://code.google.com/archive/p/simplejson/issues/34) regarding this on the google forums, but this is 10 years old, and involves using the simplejson library- an extra library seems like overkill for this, especially when there is potentially a more modern solution

Comment: @downvoters care to explain?

Comment: The issue is rather self-explanatory: ``text`` must be text. You already *did* find the standard method, namely store-as-string, yet you reject this for a nonsensical reason: it is not *meaningful* to store numeric output in text format, other than using the store-as-string approach or similar. Without further information, it is impossible to know why you reject this and thus also which alternatives are suitable.

Comment: "I need the output to be numeric" What output? The output of `ET.dump` is going to be a string (or `bytes`) anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting. I see that it is not going to work with a `float` because the [`_escape_cdata`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3b05ad7/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L1059-L1073) function uses the `in` operator (`if "&" in text`).

Also, the [docstring for the `text` attribute](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3b05ad7/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L151-L155) indicates that it is either a `string` or `None`. The [documentation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3b05ad7/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L151-L155), however, says that the "values are usually strings but may be any application-specific object", which I find misleading.

If you need to get other types when *parsing* an XML document, I recommend you use [lxml.objectify](https://lxml.de/objectify.html)